# What is the difference between &6 and /dev/fd/6?

Tags: linux, bash, socket, file-descriptors

To read from file descriptor 6 I can use `<&6` or `</dev/fd/6` (aka `/proc/self/fd/6`). Usually both work equally well. However if that file descriptor happens to be a socket, strange things happen. For example:

```
$ bash -c 'ls -l /dev/fd/6;cat /dev/fd/6' 6</dev/tcp/localhost/12345
lrwx------ 1 michas michas 64 Jan 10 19:50 /dev/fd/6 -> socket:[315010]
cat: /dev/fd/6: No such device or address
```

Here `ls` shows the descriptor is indeed present. But accessing the data is not possible this way. If I use `cat <&6` instead everything works well again.

What is the difference between both ways of accessing the file descriptor?

Is there a good way to access a descriptor if the number if given in a variable? (`</dev/fd/$fd` would work, but `<&$fd` does not.)

(The above situation can be observed on linux, but not on OpenBSD. - Seems like that file descriptor is a regular character device there.)

Comment: Is this a duplicated one http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98958/38906

Comment: Thanks. It's related but not really a duplicate.

Comment: Also related: [OS X, bash: less works on open file descriptors, cat doesn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209648)

Answer (score 6):

It's so because reading from `/dev/fd/` entries which represents sockets isn't implemented on Linux. [You can find quite a good writeup on reasoning here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33924/write-inside-a-socket-open-by-another-process-in-linux) So you can call `stat` on the link, and that's why you see it with `ls`, but access is deliberately disallowed.

Now for the second part - why does `bash -c 'ls -l /dev/fd/6; cat <&6' 6</dev/tcp/localhost/12345` work? That's because socket is read from using socket/file API, not `/proc` filesystem. This is what I've observed happening:

1. `bash` instance running in your terminal creates socket with fd 6.
2. Child `bash` runs and calls `dup2(6, 0)`, in order to attach your socket as `cat`'s `stdin`.
3. If `dup2` call didn't fail, cat reads from `stdin`.

You can reproduce and observe it with:

```
netcat -lp 12345    # in another terminal session (GNU netcat)
strace -f -e trace=open,read,write,dup2 bash -c 'ls -l /dev/fd/6; cat <&6' \
 6</dev/tcp/localhost/12345
```

If you're wondering why does the `bash` child process have access to fd 6 - file descriptors survive `fork`, and [if they aren't marked for closing on `exec`, they don't get closed there as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241000/does-exec-preserve-file-descriptors)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your direct question, "*what is the difference*?":

When you redirect from `<&6`, the shell uses a `dup2()` system call to duplicate the file descriptor.  When you (attempt to) redirect from `</dev/fd/6`, it will use `open()`.

The kernel doesn't support `open()` on sockets in `/dev/fd`; they are present in the directory for <strike>decoration</strike> information only.